How to make Navigation between views smoothly in SwiftUI
Code: with this code i am navigating to views between(ProfileView(), HomeNew, NotificationsTabView, MessageTabView) very sharp i mean something like very fast change but i need it could be more smoothly change from one view to other
because of my code if i quickly change views one by one then slightly before view dummy data design for a sec showing in current view..
so i need very smooth navigation between views. so how to achieve smooth navigation between views. plz guide me.
struct TabContainerViewNew: View {
    @Binding var index: Int?
    @State private var showSideMenu = false
    @State private var gotoSearch = false

    init(index: Binding<Int?>) {
        self._index = index
        UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
    }

    let tabs = [("Menu", "Menu_New"), ("My profile", "user"), ("Home", "MenuNew_Home"), ("Notification", "MenuNew_Notification"), ("Message", "MenuNew_Message")]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            if let index = index {
                TabView(selection: Binding(
                    get: { index },
                    set: { newValue in
                        self.index = newValue
                    }
                )) {
                    ProfileView()
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("My profile", image: "icn_settings_tab")
                        }
                        .tag(1)

                    HomeNew()
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Home", image: "icn_home_tab")
                        }
                        .tag(2)

                    NotificationsTabView()
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Notification", image: "icn_notifications_tab")
                        }
                        .tag(3)

                    MessageTabView()
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Message", image: "icn_message_tab")
                        }
                        .tag(4)
                }
                .tint(.white)
                .transition(.slide)
          }

            VStack(spacing: 0) {
          
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(0..<tabs.count) { i in
                        if tabs[i].0 == "Menu" {
                            VStack {
                                Button(action: {
                                    withAnimation {
                                        showSideMenu.toggle()
                                    }
                                }) {
                                    Image(tabs[i].1)
                                        .renderingMode(.template)
                                        .resizable()
                                        .scaledToFit()
                                        .tint(.white.opacity(0.6))
                                        .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                                        .padding(8)
                                }
                                Text(tabs[i].0)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.6))
                                    .font(.system(size: 11))
                            }
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        } else {
                            TabButton(image: tabs[i].1, title: tabs[i].0, item: i, index: $index)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 7)
                .padding(.bottom, 15)
                .padding(.top, 5)
                .background(Color.appGreen2)
            }
        }
        
        .sideMenu(isShowing: $showSideMenu) {
            SideMenuView(isShowingMenu: $showSideMenu)
        }
    }
}

struct TabButton: View {
    var image: String
    var title: String
    var item: Int
    @Binding var index: Int?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                    index = item
            }) {
                Image(image)
                    .renderingMode(.template)
                    .resizable()
                    .foregroundColor(index == item ? .white : .white.opacity(0.6))
                    .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                    .padding(8)
            }
            Text(title)
                .foregroundColor(index == item ? .white : .white.opacity(0.6))
                .fontWeight(index == item ? .bold : .regular)
                .font(.system(size: (index == item ? 11 : 11)))
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) 
    }
}


This code doesn't compile because there are too many definitions missing. This makes it very difficult to understand what the problem is or how it can be remedied. Please can you convert it to a minimal reproducible example that is complete and can be run standalone?

@BenzyNeez, plz check added full code

Unfortunately, the code is still not complete and nothing like an MRE which can be run standalone. Still missing are ProfileView, HomeNew, NotificationsTabView, MessageTabView, SearchView, SideMenuView, appGreen2 and of course all the images. These are probably not relevant for reproducing the problem, so you could omit them when preparing a proper MRE.

@BenzyNeez, ProfileView, HomeNew, NotificationsTabView, MessageTabView, SearchView, SideMenuView those are normal views u can ignore SideMenuView  bcz no no navigation here and appGreen2  can be normal green colour as well

@BenzyNeez, i need smoothly navigation between views . with this code when i click Button  then very sharply changing views.. i mean in a blink its changing.. but i need smooth kind of animation

I was asking for an MRE and didn't get one, but I think there may be a simple solution here.
Since you are already using a custom tab bar, try using .page as the .tabViewStyle. This provides a slide transition between views:
TabView( //...
) {
    // ...
}
.tint(.white)
// .transition(.slide) // not needed
.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
.animation(.easeInOut, value: index)

That's about the only animation you get with a TabView. If you're after an .opacity transition, or any other kind of transition for that matter, then you'll need to implement the change of view yourself. This is actually not very difficult, especially since you're already using a custom tab bar.
One way is to replace the TabView with a ZStack and a switch statement:
ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
    ZStack {
        switch(index) {
        case 1:
            ProfileView()
        case 3:
            NotificationsTabView()
        case 4:
            MessageTabView()
        default:
            HomeNew()
        }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .tint(.white)
    .animation(.easeInOut, value: index)

    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        // ...
    }
}


no actually not this kind.. i dont even want slide type.. i just want smooth.. like if i tap on button then in a blink it changes.. at the time i need smoothly move..

@Swift In that case, I'm not sure why you had .transition(.slide) there before. Anyway, that's about all you get with a TabView. If you're after an .opacity transition (or any other kind of transition for that matter) then you'll need to implement the change of view yourself. This is actually not very difficult, you can do it with a ZStack and a switch statement. Answer updated.

but why with this code all my views ProfileView, HomeNew, NotificationsTabView, MessageTabView are going too much top even occupies safearea as well.. but with my post code got proper good top padding.. plz let me know

if i give .top padding 50 then whole screen eg. ProfileView() whole view coming down.. i mean some 50 white colour space showing on top.. my home screen background colour is not in white colour.. but in my post code only homescreen content is in proper padding.. that is missing in this answer... but this kind of smooth only i need.. plz fix if possible.. the top padding issue

@Swift These sound like issues that relate to missing parts of the code. Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example.

no its okay fixed padding issue by adding .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom) thanks

is there any other animation except  .animation(.easeInOut, value: index) here while changing views previous view shading in current view.. easeInOut not this is there any other relevant animation ? i tried this .animation(.smooth, value: index) also same effect

@Swift I think you are asking about other transitions. Try applying different .transition modifiers to the individual views inside the ZStack. The .animation modifier only controls the speed of transition, not the style of transition.
